# One face is bigger than the others

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, faces, subdivision-surface

Making the donut and one of the faces is bigger than the other. Tried goolging the problem but I don't know all the terms to really search effectively. Is there any way to fix this?
[image: donut]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is probably to delete the face, dissolve the useless vertices, select 2 opposite edges and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Comment: Omg thank you! took a little bit of tinkering to learn to select the vertices but once I did, I used the grid fill and changed the offset to 4. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Knife Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html) to cut new edges between the verts. Just click <kbd>K</kbd>, while in Edit mode, and then select one of the Vertices. After that, just select the one on the opposite side. Now, a new cut will be done. You can finish it now by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then repeat it again, but you can also press <kbd>E</kbd> to start another cut, while still being in Cutting mode. When you finish with the grid, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm and you are done.

[image]